# Cordova: How to change the android build sdk target in project.properties

Tags: android, xml, cordova, sdk, target

I have tried to set a different android SDK version.

Here are what I put in config.xml:

> ```
> <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
> <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23"/>
> ```

After running `cordova prepare android`

In the generated AndroidManifest.xml, I did get the right setting:

> ```
> <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
> ```

But in the project.properties in the andorid folder, I still get:

> ```
> target=android-22
> ```

I need it to be

> ```
> target=android-23
> ```

What should I put in config.xml to achieve this?

FYI, my Cordova version is 5.3.1
I have installed the latest Android studio

Comment: cordova doesn't support android sdk 23, why do you want to change it?

Comment: I want to change the default build target. It is not only about sdk23.